Print torch tensor without extra spacing in between scalars
There is a huge space in between elements of my tensors when printing. I cannot read the tensor easily with this space.
How do I minimize it?
print settings I used:
torch.set_printoptions(sci_mode=False, precision=4, linewidth=200, profile="full")
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=4, linewidth=200)
Here is a torch array:

Here is the same shape np array but much more readable because no spacing:

